# Python: tarfile library turning file into a binary file

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, redhat, tarfile

My name is Luis and I would like to ask you question about the python library tarfile.

When I archive a file with tarfile, it adds some extra information to the original file, turning it to a binary file.
This happens only In the production systems, I could not reproduce it in developing machine.

Developing Machine:
Linux Mint 19
Python 2.7.15+
tarfile $Revision: 85213 $

Production:
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
Python 2.7.5
tarfile $Revision: 85213 $

Data added to the header of the archived file:
[image]

Code to archive the file:

```
with tarfile.open(destination_path, "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add(source_path, arcname=os.path.basename(source_path))
```

Once more, this happens only in the Production system.
Could you help me understand this behavior and how to act?

Best regards
Luis

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? What happens on the development machine? What do you mean by "how to act"?

Comment: On the developer machine, no binary code is added to the archived file. I want it to be the same on the production machine.

Comment: You are specifically instructing the tar to be compressed with gzip, which is never human-readable. Check that your development machine is running the same code, because I find it very hard to believe that the code above produces the output with "no binary code added".

Comment: Well I developed in my development machine and afterwards I deployed it. Using ansible, therefore is the same code. Also I tested the code